# I can't create a .txt file with a PHP script on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, txt

I am trying to make a PHP script create a `.txt` file on Heroku. It doesn't show any error message, but when I go to see if it created the file by running `ls` in the console there is nothing there.

Anyone can help me please?

```
<html>
    <body>


        <?php
            // the message
            $_msg = $_GET["email"];
            $_subject = $_GET["name"];
            $myfile = fopen($_subject .=".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

            $txt = $_msg;
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);

            header("Location: index.php", TRUE, 301);
            exit();

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works on my PC using XAMP

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Check whether you have read & write permissions for the directory where you want to create the file...

Comment: Ensure PHP error reporting / logging is switched on so you can see any errors/warnings emitted by the code (you might also want to temporarily remove the redirect so you can definitely see them in the browser).

Comment: "when i go see if it created the file"—how are you doing this?

Comment: on the console writing ls

Answer (score 0):

> when I go to see if it created the file by running `ls` in the console there is nothing there

I'm guessing when you say "in the console" here you mean by running `heroku run bash` or similar.

`heroku run` doesn't connect to your running dyno, but instead [runs the command it is given in a one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#formation-dynos-vs-one-off-dynos). Dynos [don't share filesystems](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), and even within one dyno the filesystem is ephemeral:

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

In other words, the file your PHP script generates is on a completely different filesystem from the one you see via `heroku run bash`, and any change you make to either filesystem will be lost frequently and unpredictably.

If you want to persist files long-term you'll need to save them somewhere else. A common choice is to use [Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-php). Or, depending on the type of data you are storing, a [data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) might be a better fit.